# FB blocked website for Linting URL - An internal error occurred while linting the URL

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share, social-media

Our website suddenly got blocked by Facebook and the error it show when sharing URL is

> Your post couldn't be shared, because this link goes against our
>   Community Standards
>       If you think that this doesn't go against our Community Standards, let us know.

Further trouble shooting show error as using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ show error message as

> This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of
>   scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us
>   know.
>
> Warning:Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
>
> Error Linting URL: An internal error occurred while linting the URL.

I have done through tones of page to fix this issue with so respite. i did submit to FB to fix this issue with no response as its with most of the cases.

more testing reveled on debugger mentioned below show no data returned, not sure why? as no other details are mentioned.

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fen%2F
>
> The document returned no data.

I have cross check & tested Open Graph tag and i dont see and issue. Open Graph as generate looks like

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Company Name'/>
<meta property='og:type' content='website'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='https://www.example.com/en/'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='https://www.example.com/images/page/home.jpg'/>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='www.example.com'/>
<meta name='twitter:card' content='summary_large_image' />
<meta name='twitter:description' content='Brief Description about the company which is less than 120 characters' />
<meta name='twitter:title' content='Company Name' />
<meta name='twitter:image' content='https://www.example.com/images/page/home.jpg'/>
```

Is there anything i should do different as the website is company website and doent contain any information which violate Facebook community guideline.

What should i do differently to get this resolved from my side